# how to search for the value with a certain index in an array and modify its value?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I have two arrays, the first contains two numbers and the second 12 values.

```
firstArray = [0, 6];

secondArray = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
```

I want to take the numbers of the first array and and check that index of the second array matches and then change the value of the matching ones.

In this case the output would be

```
secondArray = ["blank", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "blank", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
```

I was trying to for-loop for getting the values in firstArray but I'm gettin the indexes and not the value

```
    for (let i = 0; i < this.state.lastIndex.length; i++) {

    }
```

hay
How can I do it?
Is there any way to make it more direct than with a for-loop?

thanks for your help

Comment: "*Is there any way to make it more direct than with a for-loop?*" if you only have two items in the first array, then you can just do `secondArray[firstArray[0]]` and `secondArray[firstArray[1]]`

Comment: ```secondArray[firstArray[0]] = "blank"``` and ```secondArray[firstArray[1]] = "blank"```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a oneliner, you could use map from `Array.prototype`:

```
secondArray = secondArray.map((element, index) => firstArray.includes(index) ? "blank" : element )
```

Please note the map function returns a new array, instead of modifying the original one.

Edit: removed redundant `return` and curly-braces around the arrow function body

Comment: thank you, is the perfect solution for what I was looking for!!

Answer (score 1):

firstArray.map(e=>{if(secondArray[e]){secondArray[e]="blank"}})

Answer (score 1):

```
firstArray = [0, 6]; 
secondArray = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July","August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];

for(let i = 0; i < firstArray.length; i++) {
    secondArray[firstArray[i]]="blank";
}
console.log(secondArray);
```

**PS: All you need to do just loop through the first array, and the update the values of second array at index**