# how to check the indexes of an array with external values to generate a new one?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array and 2 variables. The two variables are numbers and the array contains 12 values.

```
const firstParam = 6;
const secondParam = 0;

originalArray = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
```

I want to take the numbers and check that index of the second array matches and then change the value of the matching ones.

In this case the output would be

```
newArray = ["blank", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "blank", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
```

I was trying with map but it's not applied

```
    const newArray = originalArray.map((element, index) => firstParam ? null : element);
```

How can I do it?
Is there any better way to get the desired result?

thanks for your help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to search for the value with a certain index in an array and modify its value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64351929/how-to-search-for-the-value-with-a-certain-index-in-an-array-and-modify-its-valu)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could take an array for the indices and check the index with [`Array#includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) and return either a new value of the old value.

```js
const
    indices = [6, 0],
    originalArray = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"],
    result = originalArray.map((v, i) => indices.includes(i) ? 'blank' : v);

console.log(...result);
```